# Prevent user from closing an application in C# or an alternate solution so that a service stays and performs the task

Tags: c#, winforms

Background: Okay, so there is a C# application designed by some C# geek that tests products and logs all data and sends the log as an email everyday at 1 pm provided the application is open.

Problem: Some of the users are logging off and closing the application, the application is unable to send the mail when the form is closed.

Question: Is there a way to stop users from closing the C# form?

OR

making a program such that even when the form is closed it runs in background and sends that mail?

OR

if any of you have a better suggestion, all is welcome.

Comment: If you're going to write malware, at least write your own malware.  We're not going to write it for you.

Comment: If it doesn't need a UI, it can be a Windows service or scheduled task. If it **does** need a UI, then it gets harder..

Comment: Logging off PC or logging off the form application?

Comment: @stuartd yes it does need a UI as all testing of the products are done with that app. then end of day it sends mail everyday.

Comment: @Servy _"sends the log as an email everyday at 1 pm provided the application is open"_ doesn't sound like malware to me?

Comment: @Servy I understand your concern. If I was knowledgeable enough to write a malware then why would I come here. If you dont want to help its okay

Comment: Split your application into two parts, a Windows Service that logs data and sends email, and a desktop app users run to perform testing.

Comment: @gitsitgo every user logs in with their username and password and they log off when they are done and end up closing the form. The needs to be running else its not sending a mail.

Comment: @DourHighArch the data is logged as a text file. then that file is read by the application counts the number of and type of units, pass and fail and then sends the mail. If I can maybe create a service that reads the text file and sends mail even when the form is closed :/ sounds good eh?

Comment: Right. What you do NOT want to do is “stop users from closing the form”. That won't work and will just annoy people. Start researching how to create and install a Windows Service. Then research how your desktop application can communicate with a service. Experiment. If you have problems you can ask here, but don't ask “how do I do that?” as your question will be closed.

Comment: @DourHighArch Thanks for the advice, I am looking at "how to create a service".